# i7-4600U and virtual machines

Tags: laptop

I would like to know if a laptop with Intel(R) Core(TM)i7-4600U @ 2.10GHz 2.70GHz , 2 cores and 4 threats , 4 Mo Cache , 8GB of RAM and 256 Go SSD is capable of running two or more virtual machines simultaneously(let's say for example windows server 2008 and ubuntu 14.04 as VMs) .
Thank you in advance

Comment: It depends what your VMs are doing, but I doubt it. For multiple VMs and good performance I'd recommend: i7 w/ 4 cores/8 threads, 16GB RAM, 500GB SSD

Comment: Technical support request — Questions asking about troubleshooting hardware or technical support for hardware are off-topic for Hardware Recommendations because the site is here to provide pre-purchase hardware recommendations and to recommend hardware for a specific task, rather than to support existing devices. You may get help on Super User.

Comment: What are your requirements?
You can over provision CPU (and let the VMs compete for the CPU time), however you cannot give your VMs more RAM (in total) than available on your machine.

Comment: Need more requirements.